# General equation related with the "vibrating circular membrane" problem, related with Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

What's the general equation related with the "vibrating circular membrane" problem, related with Bessel function of the first kind, that I can just put the "n" order number and the "m"-th positive zero, like J(0,1), that gives me, in this case, as result, the zero of function, resulting in 2.405?

Comment: If I were to call compute these zeros in Python I would end up calling the routine jdzo() in [this Fortran library](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/special_functions/special_functions.html), which has a book reference but whose algorithm looks like a set of clever numerical approximations rather than a closed-form expression. If you decide that you'd like to understand how that computation works, you might construct a related question for [scicomp.se]. It would be polite to link the two questions in their text or in their comments.

Comment: There's no equation you can just throw $m$ and $n$ into and get the zero. But, you can compute the zeroes numerically using the [scipy python package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.jn_zeros.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the wave equation for the problem, it's $\nabla^2 z = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial t^2}$. If you're asking about the solution that involves Bessel function of the first kind, it's $z = J_n (\frac{k_{mn}r}{a}) \cos (n \theta) \cos (\frac{k_{mn}vt}{a})$, where $k$ is the $m^{th}$ zero of $J_n$